# SQL: Subtract 1 day from date value of my sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM booking WHERE '$year/$month/$day' BETWEEN arrivalDate AND departureDate
```

Where arrivalDate and departureDate are date values in my tables columns.

How can I check for the day before departureDate?

IE: departureDate - 1 day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there, there is **[`- INTERVAL 1 DAY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_interval)** for this:

```
SELECT * FROM booking WHERE '$year/$month/$day' BETWEEN arrivalDate AND departureDate - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

### [Relevant sqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/19292/0)

**See also:**

- [`ADDDATE()` function in the official MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)